# Objective-C Class init parameters

Tags: objective-c, class, parameters

I'm currently starting up with some Objective-C again. The problem I have is passing variables to the native init method of a class instance.

I have this custom init in my @interface:

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        level = 1;
        NSLog(@"Debug response");
    }

    return ([NSObject init]); // return self;
}
```

And here's my App's main class:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "PlayableCharacter.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Elf", nil];

    PlayableCharacter *allendar = [[PlayableCharacter alloc] init:params];
}

@end
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I thought an NSArray object would fit the profile of an "id" C-object. Is giving init parameters illegal or must it be done in another way?

The Error states: "No visible @interface for 'PlayableCharacter' declares the selector 'init:'"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `-init` method doesn't have any params. It's equivalent to the following C:

```
void *init();

void *foo = init(bar); // error
```

If you want to call it as `-init:`, then you would declare it as

```
- (id)init:(NSArray *)params;
```

However, this is very much a non-standard naming. If you really want an init method that takes a single `NSArray`, then maybe name it something like

```
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array;
```

But from your sample code I'm guessing you don't really need an array, you just need one parameter. So instead you'd use

```
- (id)initWithCharacterClass:(NSString *)className;
```

and then call it as

```
PlayableCharacter *allendar = [[PlayableCharacter alloc] initWithCharacterClass:@"Elf"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Need to get used to the way Objective-C formats everything :). I am mainly using the NSArray in the thought of the String args[] style C uses. The Race "Elf" isn't the only thing I want to parse, as I want to be able to set the PlayableCharacter to a previous state from a Database.

Comment: @Allendar: Unless your data is best expressed as an array, you typically want to use multiple distinct parameters. For example, you wouldn't define all your C functions as `void *foo(void *args, size_t count)`, would you? You'd only use that when you actually need to accept a variable number of values. Similarly in obj-c, you can take an `NSArray*` if you need to accept a variable number of values, but if you need to take a specific small set of values, you would use separate parameters.

Comment: For this case, for readability sake, I changed it to NSMutableDictionary. Then for instance I can actually check if someone passed a "Race" value, instead of brutally checking list keys.

Comment: Did it cleanly now, at least, I hope :) >>> PlayableCharacter *allendar = [[PlayableCharacter alloc] initWithMutableDictionary:params];

Comment: @Allendar: Since you seem to have free-form parameters, using a dictionary here is probably fine. But the parameter shouldn't be mutable. You should call it either `-initWithDictionary:` (taking an `NSDictionary*`) or `-initWithParams:`.

Comment: Good idea :P. I will make them fixed :)

Comment: Short off-this-topic question; I do this superclass structure now: Entitiy -> PlayableClass and then have Race as an object inside the PlayableClass. Is it more suitable to do Entity -> Race -> PlayableClass or keep it like this? I need to Race's information to determine the base stats and certain other aspects of the PlayableClass :)

Comment: @Allendar: I doubt that it makes sense for Race to be a superclass of PlayableClass. You should probably just keep it as a property of the class.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to init with parameters then create an `init` method like this:

```
-(id)initWithParams:(NSArray *)params
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        level = 1;
        NSLog(@"Debug response");

        // Do something with params
    }

    return self;
}
```

Also, you should just return `self`, not `[NSObject init]`

Comment: Noted, had that quoted out for later research, as I wasn't sure which one to use.